# Accessing Mongrel on Ubuntu within a Windows VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtual-machine, mongrel

Hej,

i'm developing on an Ubuntu 10.04 Version. I'm using Mongrel 1.1.5. To test crossbrowser compability i want to access my local server directly out of a VM (Virtual Box OSE) runnning Windows XP Prof.

Network connection is established, a ping from Windows to ubuntu shows that the connection is established, but when i try to access my ruby on rails app via http://IpOfUbuntu:3000 i get no response.

Does anybody no what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall blocking port 3000? You can check on the ubuntu box by doing

```
sudo iptables  -L
```

If there are no firewall rules blocking access you should see something like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Yes it looks like that. There are no blocks on port 3000
Anyone else an idea?